# working with a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have an `UIScrollView` when I present a form to the user. You can see a screenshot of my storyboard over here. Below the pickers there is a submit button.

[image]

What I want to do now is, when a user presses submit. On top of the tableview appears a uitableview with all the previous set exceptions.

My question is now, how can I put a `tableview` on top of the `scrollview` when the submit button is pressed?

Hope anyone can help me!

Comment: Did you try? [scrollView addSubView:self.tableViewPreviousExceptions];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code...

```
[scrollView addSubView:tableView];
[scrollview bringSubviewToFront:tableView];
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. But what if I want to put the tableview at the top of the scrollview?

Comment: just set the frame dude.. what you exactly want ??

Comment: just add this code before my answer just add like [yourTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,yourTableView.frame.size.width,yourTableView.frame.size.height)];

Comment: hey @StefGeelen if this answer useful to you then accept the answer dude.. thanx.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you adding `UIScrollView` and `UITableView` on any base view then you should use or adding table on scroll,

in any case this must work..

`[tableview.superView bringSubviewToFront:tableView];`